# Java: How to use Comparator with arraylist as values of HashMap

Tags: java

I have this HashMap:

```
 HashMap< itemDetails, Pair<ArrayList<itemDetails>, AssociatedInfo>> AssociatedItemCasuaList = new HashMap<>();
```

where its key is class, and its values consist of pair (a= arraylist of class **itemDetails**, b= class **AssociatedInfo**):

```
class itemDetails {
    public ArrayList<Integer> itemId; 
    public float expectedSupport = 0;
    // etc
}
```

and

```
  class Pair<T, U> {

        T a;
        U b;

        Pair(T a, U b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        T getA() {
            return a;
        }

        U getB() {
            return b;
        }
    }
```

and

```
class AssociatedInfo { 
    public int noOfKCasual = 0;
    public int AssociateListStart = 0;
    public int AssociateListEnd = 0;
}
```

I want to sort the first pair of the the values of `HashMap`
which is the `ArrayList<Integer> itemId` in the class  `itemDetails`

I used this Comparator

```
 public class ItemComparator implements Comparator<ArrayList<Integer> >{
     @Override
    public int compare(final ArrayList<Integer> entry1, final ArrayList<Integer> entry2){
        if (entry1 == null && entry2 == null)
            return 0;
        if (entry1 == null)
            return 1;
        if (entry2 == null)
            return -1;
        if (entry1.isEmpty() && entry2.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        if (entry1.isEmpty())
            return 1;
        if (entry2.isEmpty())
            return -1;
        return entry1.get(0).compareTo(entry2.get(0));
    }
  }
```

I don't know how to write `Collections.sort`

```
if (AssociatedItemCasuaList.containsKey(LHS)) {
    AssociatedItemCasuaList.get(LHS).a.add(RHS2);
    AssociatedItemCasuaList.get(LHS).b.AssociateListStart = 0;
    AssociatedItemCasuaList.get(LHS).b.AssociateListEnd += 1;
    AssociatedItemCasuaList.get(LHS).b.noOfKCasual += 1;
} else {
    ArrayList<itemDetails> ArrayListRHS = new ArrayList<itemDetails>();
    ArrayListRHS.add(RHS2);
    AssociatedInfo AttribAssociatedInfo1 = new AssociatedInfo();
    AttribAssociatedInfo1.noOfKCasual = 1;
    AttribAssociatedInfo1.AssociateListStart = 0;
    AttribAssociatedInfo1.AssociateListEnd = 0;
    AssociatedItemCasuaList.put(LHS, new Pair(ArrayListRHS, AttribAssociatedInfo1));
}
//      Collections.sort(AssociatedItemCasuaList.get(LHS), new ItemComparator());
```

**Update:
Example:**

```
AssociatedItemCasuaList < **key**=LHS, **value**=Pair<a, b> >
```

**Let key=LHS:**

```
LHS.itemId=1
LHS.expectedSupport=87.5
```

**and values = Pair < a, b >**

Let focus here in `a` only in this example.

```
a= ArrayList<itemDetails>
```

Let `itemDetails RH2`

and every time (in loop) I add **RHS2** to key **LHS** as:

```
AssociatedItemCasuaList.get(LHS).a.add(RHS2)
```

here `RHS2` takes different values every  time

```
  RHS2.itemId
  RHS2.expectedSupport
```

until now, I don't have problem.

I want to sort the ArrayList in `a` (that I filled with `RHS2`) based on its itemId

Comment: Just checking: have you overridden `equals` and `hashCode` in the `itemDetails` class?

Comment: Also, what do you need to do? Could you explain "sort the first pair of the the values of HashMap which is the ArrayList<Integer> itemId in the class itemDetails"?

Comment: Please follow Java coding conventions: Names of types (classes, interfaces, enums) always start with a capital letter. Names of fields, variables and methods always start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: _"I want to sort the first pair of the the values of `HashMap` which is the `ArrayList<Integer> itemId` in the class `itemDetails`"_ -- this doesn't seem to make any sense. You will need to explain more clearly.

Comment: @mick-mnemonic yes  I did overridden `equals` and `hashCode` in the itemDetails class. I want sort `RHS2` based on itemId. I will update my question with example.

Comment: Mi suggestion is you'd better organize that complicated structure into _abstractions_: Make one for `ArrayList<itemDetails>`, another for `Pair<Array, AssocInfo>`, etc. It will produce much clearer code.

Comment: Can you please rewrite this question as a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact I didn't understand a single word, what about this:

```
public class ItemComparator2 implements Comparator<itemDetails> {
  Comparator myComp = new ItemComparator();
  @Override
  public int compare(itemDetails a, itemDetails b){
    return myComp.compare(a.itemId, b.itemId);
  }
}

// ...

Collections.sort(AssociatedItemCasuaList.get(LHS).getA(), new ItemComparator2());
```